# More complete installer

Tags: 18.04

Is there a more complete installer for 18.04.3?

I install on my VM with internet access and apt list returns 65K+ entries.

I install on my standalone laptop and apt list returns 4667 entries.

Of course, my VM with internet access reaches out and installs a whole bunch of stuff automatically.

How do I make consistent builds across machines with no internet connection?

Thanks,